# What causes an express session to regenerate?

Tags: session, express

What causes express sessions to be generated on a new page load?

I'm only seeing it happen for users that were on my system before I moved my server to a new box.

New users can create logins and authenticate no problem.

An existing user attempts to login and they get a new session when the login process takes them from "/login" to "/authed".

I know this is happening because I'm looking at the req.sessionID. For new users it stays the same throughout, for existing users (ie from the old box) it regenerates.

Here's a sample of a failing request - on login im setting session vars so I need that same session on the /authed request

```
2015-01-28T20:01:19.548Z : worker 1 : POST : /login
sess_id : hx_9U_1IXYvtgrGEwvFAWGcVKCR0e-zH
sess_id : hx_9U_1IXYvtgrGEwvFAWGcVKCR0e-zH

2015-01-28T20:01:19.760Z : worker 1 : GET : /authed
sess_id : nZWUdTgCnba_vPR8ZgHLo3WkXZW-25UY
```

Edit: I'm using redis as a store for my session.
Thanks

Comment: I spent 10 or so hours on this and decided to just rebuild the box from scratch which solved my problem. So clearly, I did something that I don't remember being material, which in fact, was hugely material.